# Variance Estimator in Simple Random Sampling Without Replacement

Tags: probability, statistics, statistical-inference, parameter-estimation

I have to find the unbiased estimator of population variance under simple random sampling without replacement.

The hint  for the demonstration is:
$$ \frac{1}{N} \sum_{k =1}^{N} (x_{k} - \bar{x_{U}})^2 = \frac{1}{2N^2} \sum_{k =1}^{N}\sum_\underset{\Large{l\neq k}}{l=1}^{N} (x_{k} - \bar{x_{l}})^2 $$

I start like this, but I don't know if this is right:

$\implies \frac{1}{2N^2}\sum_\underset{\Large{l\neq k}}{l=1}^{N} (x_{k}- \bar{x_{l}})^2$

$\implies \frac{1}{2N^2}\sum_\underset{\Large{l\neq k}}{l=1}^{N} (x_{k}^2 - 2x_{l}x_{k} + \bar{x_{l}}^2)$

$\implies \frac{1}{2N^2}\sum_\underset{\Large{l\neq k}}{l=1}^{N} x_{k}^2 -\sum_\underset{\Large{l\neq k}}{l=1}^{N}2\bar{x_{l}}x_{k} +\sum_\underset{\Large{l\neq k}}{l=1}^{N}\bar{x_{l}}^2$

Here I am stuck.

Comment: What is $x_k,x_U$? Have you taken any expectations?

Comment: I have clear that $x_{U}$  is the population mean. But I think that $x_{k}$ is my sample observation

Comment: The hint is an identity for any list of numbers $(x_1,...,x_N)$, where $x_U:={1\over N}\sum_{i=1}^N;$ so it holds regardless of whether $(x_1,...,x_N)$ is a population or a sample. (If $(x_1,...,x_N)$ is a *sample*, then the identity won't hold unless $x_U$ is the *sample* mean; similarly for population and population mean.) You can apply this directly to the definition of the sample variance of sample $(y_1,...,y_n)$, so its expectation involves $E(y_{k} - y_{l})^2=E(y_1-y_2)^2= 2\left(\sigma^2-\text{cov}(y_1,y_2)\right)$, where $\sigma^2$ is the population variance, etc.

Comment: My comment above refers to the identity as originally posted (proved [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Population_variance)). But after your recent edit, which added bars in the RHS, that equation now seems unintelligible.  (The original identity can be used in the way I described to derive an unbiased estimator, but getting the covariance term is tedious.)

Comment: I found a way to get the covariance term easily, and posted it in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $(y_1,...,y_n)$ be a simple random sample without replacement from population $(x_1,...,x_N).$ Then the population mean and variance are, respectively,
$$\begin{align}\mu:&={1\over N}\sum_{i=1}^Nx_i\\
\sigma^2:&={1\over N}\sum_{i=1}^N(x_i-\mu)^2.\end{align}$$
Following is a sketch of how to show that
$$\begin{align}E\left({N-1\over N}{1\over n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n(y_i-\bar{y})^2\right)=\sigma^2.\end{align}$$

---

**Aside**: Some authors differ on the definition of "population variance", taking it to be the quantity
$$S^2:={N\over N-1}\sigma^2= {1\over N-1}\sum_{i=1}^N(x_i-\mu)^2,$$
presumably to allow the above unbiasedness result to be written as follows:

$$\begin{align}E\left({1\over n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n(y_i-\bar{y})^2\right)=S^2.\end{align}$$

---

By the OP's identity (as originally posted, which is proved [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Population_variance)),

$$\begin{align}E\left(\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i =1}^{n} (y_{i} - \bar{y})^2\right) &= \frac{1}{2n^2} \sum_{i =1}^{n}\sum_\underset{\Large{j\neq i}}{j=1}^{n} E(y_i - y_j)^2\\
&={1\over 2n^2} n(n-1)E(y_1-y_2)^2\\
&={1\over 2n^2} n(n-1)E\left((y_1-\mu)-(y_2-\mu)\right)^2\\
&={1\over 2n^2} n(n-1)E\left((y_1-\mu)^2+(y_2-\mu)^2-2(y_1-\mu)(y_2-\mu)\right)\\
&={1\over 2n^2} n(n-1)\,2(\sigma^2-\text{cov}(y_1,y_2))\\
&={1\over 2n^2} n(n-1)\,2(\sigma^2-(-{\sigma^2\over N-1}))\\[2ex]
&={n-1\over n}{N\over N-1}\sigma^2.
\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\text{QED}\end{align}$$
In the above, the covariance term is obtained as follows, because each of the $N(N-1)$ possible outcomes for $(y_1-\mu)(y_2-\mu)$ is equally likely:
$$\begin{align}\text{cov}(y_1,y_2)
&=E\left((y_1-\mu)(y_2-\mu)\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{N(N-1)} \sum_{i =1}^{N}\sum_\underset{\Large{j\neq i}}{j=1}^{N} (x_i-\mu)(x_j-\mu)\\
&=\frac{1}{N(N-1)} (-N\sigma^2)\\
&=-{\sigma^2\over N-1}
\end{align}$$
where we have used
$$\sum_{i =1}^{N}\sum_\underset{\Large{j\neq i}}{j=1}^{N} (x_i-\mu)(x_j-\mu)=-N\sigma^2$$
which is a consequence of the following identity:
$$\begin{align}0^2=\left(\sum_{i=1}^N(x_i-\mu)\right)^2 
&=\sum_{i=1}^N(x_i-\mu)^2 + \sum_{i =1}^{N}\sum_\underset{\Large{j\neq i}}{j=1}^{N} (x_i-\mu)(x_j-\mu)\tag{*}\\
&=N\sigma^2 + \sum_{i =1}^{N}\sum_\underset{\Large{j\neq i}}{j=1}^{N} (x_i-\mu)(x_j-\mu).\end{align}$$

Note that (*) is just a special case (with $z_i=x_i-\mu$, so $\sum z_i=0$) of the general identity
$$\left(\sum_{i=1}^N z_i\right)^2 
=\sum_{i=1}^Nz_i^2 + \sum_{i =1}^{N}\sum_\underset{\Large{j\neq i}}{j=1}^{N}z_iz_j.
$$

Sources:

[http://dept.stat.lsa.umich.edu/~moulib/sampling.pdf](http://dept.stat.lsa.umich.edu/%7Emoulib/sampling.pdf)
https://issuu.com/patrickho77/docs/mth_432a_-_introduction_to_sampling